# Firefox like inspecting element

Tags: javascript, css

I am building my website with inspecting elements option to inspect each elements separately like firebug. I like to built the styles like newer version of Firefox which will blur all the elements except the selected element. Any idea on how to do this? The example of the needed output is given below.

**EDIT :** Please note that, here the element i need to select may have lower DOM hierarchy than the other elements. For eg. i may need to gray out the body container and if i select some internal elements which should not have the grey effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/T7PyK/

Clicking any element will show overlay and isolate the element. 
Clicking overlay will undo that.

JS:

```
$('*').on("click", function( e ) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    var self = $(this),
        overlay = $('#overlay');

    if ( !self.hasClass('active') ) {

        if ( self.is(':not(#overlay)') ) {
            self.addClass('active');
        }
        overlay.fadeTo(400, 0.7);

    }
    if ( self.hasClass('active') ) {

        overlay.on("click", function() {
            overlay.fadeOut(400, function() {
                self.removeClass('active');
                });
        });

    }

});
​
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.active {
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 101 !important;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #111;
}
​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: @Udhay I'd like to point out something. When clicked, the element is given among other things, a white background, which may not be desired if you have parent element with different color. You'll see how it looks if you click on any separate element inside the green area, like a bolded out text http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/T7PyK/1/

Answer (score 1):

Put a div with a background color of black, 100% width/height, absolute positioning and left/top of 0, and an opacity of somewhere between 0 and 1 (eg. 0.5).  That gives you the "gray out the page effect".

Then, put the text that you don't want grayed out in a separate div that's higher in the DOM hierarchy (or at the same level but with a higher z-index), so that it won't get covered up by your graying-out div.

Comment: Just tried this to answer the question:

1. 100% height doesn't imply filling the entire parent container - this is browser-specific.
2. The higher z-index approach did not work for it. Theoretically, this makes sense but I could not get this working.

Comment: @Hope I Helped, 1. Actually, for absolutely positioned elements it generally does imply filling the entire window (not parent container).  If you're not seeing that, maybe you should post a SO with the code?  Alternatively you could always use JS to calculate the window height and set it explicitly, but that really shouldn't be necessary.  2. Z-index is very misunderstood.  It is only relevant when two elements overlap and are at the SAME LEVEL of the DOM hierarchy.  If you have DIV's A and B, and a DOM of BODY>A>B B will ALWAYS overlap A, no matter what their z-indexs are.

Comment: But here i need to apply the opacity for which the DOM Hierarchy is low. So is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery overlay effect along with some CSS..

hit this link:  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/12/03/css-and-jquery-tutorial-overlay-with-slide-out-box/